# What causes this code to trigger implicit int narrowing?

Tags: c++, c++11, unsigned, narrowing

The following code makes clang to fail when `-Wc++11-narrowing`  is specified

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint8_t numbers[];
extern int n;

uint8_t test(int num) {
    uint8_t a{n > 0 ? *numbers : 2};
    return a;
}
```

(Same code in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/nTKqT7WGd)

```
8:15: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    uint8_t a{n > 0 ? *numbers : 2};
```

I read the standard and related issues but I cannot comprehend why a ternary operation with two results that are `uint8_t` or can be transparently narrowed`uint8_t` (i.e: constant 2) result in a promotion to `int` that then wants to be explicitly narrowed.

Can someone explain why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: This should be fixable by casting the constant to the expected type `uint8_t{2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second operand to the conditional expression has type `uint8_t`. The third operand, the literal `2`, has type `int`.

When the second and third operands to a conditional expression are of different arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed in order to bring them to their common type. [[expr.cond]/7.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#7.2)

In this case the usual arithmetic conversions involve the promotion of both types, namely `uint8_t` and `int`. [[expr.arith.conv]/1.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.5)

Because `int` can represent all values of type `uint8_t`, the result of the promotion of `uint8_t` is `int`. `int` is unaffected by integral promotions and remains `int`. [[conv.prom]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom)

The result of the conditional expression has type `int`. A conversion from `int` to `uint8_t` is narrowing, since `uint8_t` cannot represent all values of type `int`.

Comment: Thanks! Your post made me think that I was looking at the wrong place. I wrongly assumed that an integer literal would be typed with the smallest type where it could fit. According  to https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#3 it kind of works like that, but only starting from `int`. And also depends on the constant prefix to see what types are available to fit!.
I don't know too much about stack ovefrlow and as I think this is the core of my question it would be nice to include it in the answer. Do you think it's ok to update your answer to include this?

Comment: @MiguelÁngel I updated the answer to mention that `2` has type `int`.